# Database design for a limited historical data per user

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to store data related to timer sessions. My MySQL table looks like this:

```
user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
timer_start_time TIMESTAMP
timer_end_time TIMESTAMP
```

There are many users (>10 000) that do several (<10) timer sessions every day. However, I need to store only the **5 most recent ones**. So there can only be 5 records per user. How do I design a schema that adheres to these requirements and remains performant?

I'm considering storing JSON objects in VARCHAR, but have heard that it's a bad practice.

I would prefer to use MySQL for this, but I would consider switching to any other database given the performance gains.

Comment: "most recent" -- based on `start_time`?  or `end_time`?

Comment: Most recent records based on 'end_time'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan A:  Don't enforce the "limit of 5" when inserting.  We can probably handle a billion rows without stressing performance or disk space.

Plan B:  As you insert a new timer for a user, delete the oldest of 6 (if there are 6) for that user.  That limits the table size to 50K rows -- a trivial table size.

I assume the "10" you mention is not enforced?  If it is, perhaps the answer is to store 10 instead of 5.  That allows for enforcing the two limits (in different ways).

This might suffice for removing the 6th oldest "timer" for a given user

```
DELETE FROM tbl
    WHERE user_id = ?
    ORDER BY end_time
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5;
```

Can a user have two timers with the same end_time?  If not, then I recommend

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, end_time)
```

That will make some of the operations efficient.

You might also need

```
INDEX(end_time)
```

to handle other actions that you hinted at.

Comment: For plan A: I'm not fond of this strategy as I won't be using any of the records apart from the 5 most recently saved. Seems like a waste of space to store unusable data. For plan B: This seems reasonable in terms of scaling storage, but very expensive performance-wise. Would it really be that much worse to store JSON instead? Or maybe document databases would be better suited here?

Comment: JSON seems like the least efficient, due to difficulty in ordering/searching/updating.  Sketch out the SQL for each case, then we can discuss space and performance in more detail.

Comment: @Kaspis245 "*For plan B: This seems reasonable in terms of scaling storage, but very expensive performance-wise.*" - This is not the least bit expensive when indexed properly, especially on a tiny table like Rick points out yours would be. "*Would it really be that much worse to store JSON instead?*" - Agreed with Rick, that storing everything in a denormalized JSON structure would be inefficient.

Comment: @Kaspis245 Think of it this way, what's faster: Storing a single piece of paper per user with all 5 sessions written on it, in a random pile on the floor. Every time you need to add a session you need to find that piece of paper, shred it, and write a new one up - **re-writing** the other 4 sessions that didn't change (JSON approach). Or you store a separate piece of paper for each session per user, in a filing cabinet, sorted by user and session. Anytime you need to add a new session, you just find the oldest one in the sorted filing cabinet, shred it, and write only 1 session on a new paper.

Comment: @J.D. I guess it all boils down to the question of what is faster: finding 5 records, deleting the oldest of them, and inserting a new one. Or finding one record and updating its JSON value. I imagine that when the number of records is low, the first option is faster, but at some point JSON-based option overcomes in performance, no?

Comment: @Kaspis245 With an indexed table, you don't find 5 records to delete 1, you can **directly seek to the oldest 1** and only delete that oldest 1 (as my previous comment's example mentions). With a JSON approach, depending on implementation, you would have to re-write the entire JSON, which would require touching all 5 sessions. And again, depending on implementation, finding which JSON to update would be like searching through a random stack of papers as opposed to a sorted stack of papers (like an indexed table). There's really no case where JSON is faster, and instead it's usually slower.

Comment: Not to mention, with the JSON approach, the data of 5 sessions is stored on disk together as a single unit. When you need to update one value in the JSON, the entire JSON of 5 values needs to be loaded off disk and into memory. This part of the update process is implicitly 5x the amount of work than directly seeking to the single oldest session in an indexed table, which only requires loading that 1 session off disk. (I simplified how it all works, but effectively this is true, to demonstrate the point.)

Comment: Two more factors:  (1) Size of each of the 5 items (a pair of timestamps is relatively small -- leading to a vote for json).  (2) Whether the INDEX can "directly seek to the oldest" (it is easy to make such an index -- a vote for separate rows.  Both methods do 1 Select and 1 write (update or insert); so this does not provide a vote either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure about the 5x2 timestamp limit then you can set up a wide table with user_id and 5x2 timestamp columns, user_id becomes unique in the table and you update entire rows application-side. This would also allow you to move to NoSQL approaches indexed by user.

Migrating this data should be pretty trivial however, and you could generate the above schema with a short SQL view (to be materialised during downtime)  so I would recommend sticking with the general-purpose table and migrating when you have an actual performance issue. At this time you will have a better understanding of performance-critical use cases/pain points so your testing and optimisation will be better. And who knows, you might find the historical logs useful in unanticipated ways.